# comparing two csv files in python that have different data sets

Tags: python-3.x, csv

using python, I want to compare two csv files but only compare row2 of the first csv against row0 of the second csv, but print out in a new csv file only the lines where there are no matches for the compared rows.

Example....

currentstudents.csv contains the following information

```
Susan,Smith,susan.smith@mydomain.com,8
John,Doe,john.doe@mydomain.com,9
Cool,Guy,cool.guy@mydomain.com,3
Test,User,test.user@mydomain.com,5
```

previousstudents.csv contains the following information

```
susan.smith@mydomain.com
john.doe@mydomain.com
test.user@mydomain.com
```

After comparing the two csv files, a new csv called NewStudents.csv should be written with the following information:

```
Cool,Guy,cool.guy@mydomain.com,3
```

Here is what I have, but this fails to produce what I need....The below code will work, if I omit all data except the email address in the original currentstudents.csv file, but then I dont end up with the needed data in the final csv file.

```
def newusers():

for line in fileinput.input(r'C:\work\currentstudents.csv', inplace=1):
    print(line.lower(), end='')


with open(r'C:\work\previousstudents.csv', 'r') as t1, open(r'C:\work\currentstudents.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open(r'C:\work\NewStudents.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for (line[0]) in filetwo:
        if (line[0]) not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This script writes `NewStudents.csv`:

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv', newline='') as csvfile1, \
     open('sample2.csv', newline='') as csvfile2, \
     open('NewStudents.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile3:

    reader1 = csv.reader(csvfile1)
    reader2 = csv.reader(csvfile2)
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile3)
    
    emails = set(row[0] for row in reader2)

    for row in reader1:
        if row[2] not in emails:
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

The content of `NewStudents.csv`:

```
Cool,Guy,cool.guy@mydomain.com,3
```

Answer (score 0):

- With a [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html) option

  - For small files it's not going to matter, but for larger files, the vectorized operations of pandas will be significantly faster than iterating through `emails` (multiple times) with `csv`.
- Read the data with [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
- Merge the data with [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

  - The columns do not have names in the question, so columns are selected by column index.
- Select the desired new students with [Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `[all_students._merge == 'left_only']`.

  - [`.iloc[:, :-2]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position) selects all rows, and all but last two columns.

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the two csv files
cs = pd.read_csv('currentstudents.csv', header=None)
ps = pd.read_csv('previousstudents.csv', header=None)

# merge the data
all_students = cs.merge(ps, left_on=2, right_on=0, how='left', indicator=True)

# select only data from left_only
new_students = all_students.iloc[:, :-2][all_students._merge == 'left_only']

# save the data without the index or header
new_students.to_csv('NewStudents.csv', header=False, index=False)

# NewStudents.csv
Cool,Guy,cool.guy@mydomain.com,3
```